# Cancel command in the console

Tags: c++, language-agnostic

The program has a some commands for different operations. Some of the operations require data to be input by the user. Some of them can become a bit long, the user can make a mistake while inputing, he/she can chose a wrong command and decide to cancel the current operation.

I am not sure if there is an easy way to make a "Cancel operation" command when the ESC button gets pressed, while using a single thread.

How can easily I make a "Cancel operation" command in the console when a certain button gets pressed?

I think this is a language agnostic problem, but I am using C++ so I would like examples written in this language.

Comment: Off-hand, I would say that this depends very much on the operating system and language being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do everything from a single thread and you don't have external apps to do your work I see no other solution than executing a single step of work (whatever that work is) and constantly polling for key press in a fashion similar to how OSes deal with multi-tasking in a single-core environment (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-sharing)

If you're dealing with lower-level issues go for an interrupt-driven way of detecting user activity (ISRs and such).